# Pandas vs JSON library to read a JSON file in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas

It seems that I can use both pandas and/or json to read a json file, i.e.

```
import pandas as pd
pd_example = pd.read_json('some_json_file.json')
```

or, equivalently,

```
import json
json_example = json.load(open('some_json_file.json'))
```

So my question is, what's the difference and which one should I use? Is one way recommended over another, are there certain situations where one is better than the other, etc. ? Thanks.

Comment: It depends what need - `pd.read_json` return `DataFrame`, `json.load` return `dictionary`

Comment: `pandas` can load a certain type of json object.... a list of dicts with the same keys. Its advantage is it uses less space to store the content in numpy arrays. That's not very helpful if you don't want to do pandasy things to the data. json will decode any arbitrary structure, which is the more general case.

Answer (score 10):

### It Depends.

When you have a single JSON structure inside a json file, use `read_json` because it loads the JSON directly into a DataFrame. With `json.loads`, you've to load it into a python dictionary/list, and *then* into a DataFrame - an unnecessary two step process.

Of course, this is under the assumption that the structure is directly parsable into a DataFrame. For non-trivial structures (usually of the form of complex nested lists-of-dicts), you may want to use `json_normalize` instead.

On the other hand, with a JSON *lines* file, the story becomes different. From my experience, I've found loading a JSON lines file with `pd.read_json(..., lines=True)` is actually slightly *slower* on large data (tested on ~50k+ records once), and to make matters worse, cannot handle rows with errors - the entire read operation fails. In contrast, you can use `json.loads` on each line of your file inside a try-except brace for some robust code which actually ends up being a few clicks faster. Go figure.

Use whatever fits the situation.

Comment: This assumes that the json holds a list of dicts for pandas and that pandas will be a useful tool for processing the data. There are many json API's out there and that is frequently not the case.

Comment: @tdelaney of course, that is the base assumption here (otherwise why would you even think of using read_json in the first place :p)

Comment: Agreed, but I think that's what this question is about: _which one should I use_. I depends on what the data is and what you want to do with it. pandas would suck particularly bad if you wanted to push it into mongodb, for example.

Comment: @tdelaney It seems I gave the OP too much credit here; if that really is the case then this question is way too broad to answer (think about it). It's like someone asks you whether they should order a bowl of salad or the spaghetti and meatballs at a restaurant that may best be known for its sushi. I assumed here that the OP knew what they wanted to achieve by using one vs the other.

Comment: @tdelaney I guess perhaps I can try and re-phrase my question to be more specific then -- what kind of data is json good for, and what kind of data is pandas good for? It's not obvious to me why using pandas to push to mongodb would suck.

Comment: @KunalJathal Do you have a specific use case in mind or are you asking for the sake of asking? If you really don't have a concrete use case then I'm sorry, but I'm not about to go writing a blog post to enumerate all the use cases for you because there are thousands.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I have a JSON file that contains entries that are mostly lists, some strings, and a single dict. I want to parse this JSON to do a bit of processing on the lists and eventually build a new matrix, that is going to be fed into a machine learning classifier as the feature matrix for it. I get that pandas reads stuff into a dataframe and json into a dict, but given that both are eventually parsable to iterate over / extract lists, i'm wondering if it matters which one i use.

Comment: @KunalJathal I've said all I have to in my answer. Try doing it with each and see which is the easiest, that's all I can say beyond this.

Comment: Not sure why you asked me for my use case if it wasn't going to matter anyway since 'you've said all you have to say', but OK.

Comment: @KunalJathal I asked because you seemed to not be satisfied with my answer but based on what you said in your last comment, it answers your question, no?

Comment: I think the question is perfectly valid where it is required to understand which approach should be used.. Even I had the same question today .... I need to know which way to use between the two ways of creating a dataframe in pandas where input is a json file... @KunalJathal ... Which way did you finally started using ?

Comment: @NishantSharma I ended up using pandas; not because it was particularly suited for my needs, but just because my python work was part of a school course where pandas was one of the items on the curriculum for study anyway.