# ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

- I want to read in a JSON file in to my Jupiter notebook as a pandas dataframe.
- macOS 10.12, Python 3.7, pandas 0.24.2
- my dataset: https://open.fda.gov/apis/drug/label/download/
- Similar question with same error message (I have tried to use the solution from here but gives me the same error message): [Read JSON to pandas dataframe - ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49505872/read-json-to-pandas-dataframe-valueerror-mixing-dicts-with-non-series-may-lea)

```
import json
import pandas as pd

data = json.load(open('drug-label-0001-of-0008.json'))
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

- As this answer says I am not doing double conversion: [Pandas vs JSON library to read a JSON file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50167809/pandas-vs-json-library-to-read-a-json-file-in-python)
  His code just works, mine gets an error:

```
import pandas as pd
pd_example = pd.read_json('some_json_file.json')
```

- My code is similar but I get the following error:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json('drug-label-0008-of-0008.json')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-77b3c3e486fc> in <module>
----> 1 df = pd.read_json('drug-label-0008-of-0008.json')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json/json.py in read_json(path_or_buf, orient, typ, dtype, convert_axes, convert_dates, keep_default_dates, numpy, precise_float, date_unit, encoding, lines, chunksize, compression)
    425         return json_reader
    426 
--> 427     result = json_reader.read()
    428     if should_close:
    429         try:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json/json.py in read(self)
    535             )
    536         else:
--> 537             obj = self._get_object_parser(self.data)
    538         self.close()
    539         return obj

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json/json.py in _get_object_parser(self, json)
    554         obj = None
    555         if typ == 'frame':
--> 556             obj = FrameParser(json, **kwargs).parse()
    557 
    558         if typ == 'series' or obj is None:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json/json.py in parse(self)
    650 
    651         else:
--> 652             self._parse_no_numpy()
    653 
    654         if self.obj is None:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json/json.py in _parse_no_numpy(self)
    869         if orient == "columns":
    870             self.obj = DataFrame(
--> 871                 loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None)
    872         elif orient == "split":
    873             decoded = {str(k): v for k, v in compat.iteritems(

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    390                                  dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
    391         elif isinstance(data, dict):
--> 392             mgr = init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    393         elif isinstance(data, ma.MaskedArray):
    394             import numpy.ma.mrecords as mrecords

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype)
    210         arrays = [data[k] for k in keys]
    211 
--> 212     return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    213 
    214 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in arrays_to_mgr(arrays, arr_names, index, columns, dtype)
     49     # figure out the index, if necessary
     50     if index is None:
---> 51         index = extract_index(arrays)
     52     else:
     53         index = ensure_index(index)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in extract_index(data)
    318 
    319             if have_dicts:
--> 320                 raise ValueError('Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to '
    321                                  'ambiguous ordering.')
    322 

ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use python's built in JSON handling capabilities :

```
import json

with open("drug-label-0008-of-0008.json", "r") as read_file:
    data = json.load(read_file)
```

"When you have a single JSON structure inside a json file, use read_json because it loads the JSON directly into a DataFrame. With json.loads, you've to load it into a python dictionary/list, and then into a DataFrame - an unnecessary two step process. [Pandas vs JSON library to read a JSON file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50167809/pandas-vs-json-library-to-read-a-json-file-in-python) "